# Bootstrap: can't see background if I use the defined grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a two-column design using Bootstrap 3. The left column has a form, and the right column has an explicative text. Behind both columns, I have a background with an image. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="contenido_principal">

<div id="formulario"  class="col-md-6">
<form id="pedido" action="" method="post" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
          <h4>Data to be input:</h4>
        <input name="datos" type="number" min="1" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputBags" placeholder="Introduzca un número" required>
    <section id="botonsubmit">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </section>

</form>
</div>

<section id="explicacion" class="col-md-6">
Take advantage of our awesome offers!!!

 Bla bla bla bla bla
</section>
```

As you can see, the left column is the "formulario" DIV, and the right column is the "explicacion" SECTION. And here is my CSS:

```
main{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 650px;
}

main header h3{
    color:#2176C9;
}

section{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

section p{
    margin-top: 20px;
}


#contenido_principal {
    background-color: green;
/*    background-image: url('../img/layout/fondo_form.jpg');
 Instead of an image, I'm putting the BG as green to demostrate the effect */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#formulario {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px;
}

#pedido{
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: table;   
}

#pedido section{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 80%;
}

#pedido section h4 {
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;   
}

#pedido section h5 {
    margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;   
}

#pedido #next{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

(I've edited the CSS so that, instead of loading an image, it shows the background as green).

Now, The code above as-is shows the two columns on white, and you can't see any of the green background. However, if I remove the `class="col-md-6"` part, the background becomes visible.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to work with Bootstrap, you need to wrap your columns in a div with class "row" (see Bootstrap documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid))

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

So in your case you need something like:

```
<div id="contenido_principal">
    <div class="row"> <!-- Missing!! -->
        <div id="formulario" class="col-md-6">
            <form id="pedido" action="" method="post" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
                 <h4>Data to be input:</h4>

                <input name="datos" type="number" min="1" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputBags" placeholder="Introduzca un número" required>
                <section id="botonsubmit">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </section>
            </form>
        </div>
        <section id="explicacion" class="col-md-6">Take advantage of our awesome offers!!! Bla bla bla bla bla</section>
    </div>
</div>
```